# Objective-C: Why is this a memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am getting a memory leak in my objective-C code that I don't understand. I have this code in a method that gets called several times:

```
AnalyzeBpm *analyzer  = [[AnalyzeBpm alloc] init];  

while( sample != NULL)
{
//do something with analyzer
}

[analyzer release];
```

When I run this code through Instruments, I get a leak everytime I allocate Analyze Bpm(which is a couple of hundred times). I looked at my AnalyzeBpm class, and everything I allocate in that class gets freed or deallocated. So why is this code creating a memory leak?

Comment: Don't you retain "analyzer" in the "do something" while () block?

Comment: What do you do with "analyzer" in the loop?  The snippet you have here would not lead to a leak.  Also, are you running this in the iOS simulator, because sometimes I find that shows a few extra leaks that are not present on the device.

Comment: I hate to say this, but you may still be overlooking something inside your AnalyzeBpm class.  Try running the static Analyzer tool on your code and see if it comes up with anything?

Comment: @L7ColWinters The allocation and release is done properly here.

Comment: Could you post your custom AnalyzeBpm:init method if it exists. You probably make an unneeded retain somewhere between your init (which retains) and your release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Instruments identifies a leak, it is showing you the line of code that is allocating the leak, not the line of code that causes the leak.

Somewhere something is retaining `analyzer` without releasing it.  You need to find that unbalanced `retain`.  It may or may not be in the `AnalyzeBpm` class.

Answer (score 3):

Your alloc-init and release are balanced, so it has to be something else — something in your while loop.